# Calculate memory of a Map Entry

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a Map(String, String) and I want to find the memory size of an Entry and the Map in total. I read somewhere that Instrumentation might be useful ([Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html)). Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do plenty of things with instrumentation, but what's your main goal? A profiler can tell you how much memory a map takes. What are your Map entries?

Comment: Both key and value are strings. The main purpose is to calculate the memory consumption of the Map object while the application is running.

Comment: I am interested in the relative consumption per item for the various map types so I can make the speed vs memory trade off.  

Each map type has a different per-value overhead.
ie: a hash map has a different use per value than a TreeMap, or smallest memory binary search of an array [key,value,key,value, ...] of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blank instance of `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` should be 24 bytes for 64-bit JVM and 12 bytes for 32-bit JVM. Here is a technique by @PeterLawrey I found useful, based on [MemoryUsageExamplesTest](https://code.google.com/p/core-java-performance-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/com/google/code/java/core/sizeof/MemoryUsageExamplesTest.java):

```
System.out.printf("The average memory used by simple entry is %.1f bytes%n", new SizeofUtil() {
    @Override
    protected int create() {
        Map.Entry<String, String> e = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>(null, null);
        return 1;
    }
}.averageBytes());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ObjectOutputStream to write the object to a ByteArrayOutputstream and check the length of the resultant byte array.

Obviously your Map.Entry will need to implement Serializable.

```
public int getSizeInBytes(Serializable someObject) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
    objectOut.writeObject(someObject);
    objectOut.flush();
    return byteOut.toByteArray().length;
}

public int getSizeBits(Serializable someObject) {
    return getSizeInBytes(someObject) * 8;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That's another possible solution. I'll give it a try to compare the answer to the solution provided above.